# Deserialize a name as a value using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

Is it possible to deserialize a name as a value?

I've got some JSON like this:

```
{
  "id": "106906",
  "data": {
    "SER1": {
      "events": [
        {
          "timestamp": "2020-11-11T10:28:40.728600Z",
          "type": "high"
        }
      ]
    },
    "SER2": {
      "events": [
        {
          "timestamp": "2020-11-11T10:28:40.728600Z",
          "type": "high"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The C# classes I'm using are like this:

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 

public class Event    
{
    public DateTime timestamp { get; set; } 
    public string type { get; set; } 
}

public class Device    
{
    public string Id { get; set; } 
    public List<Event> events { get; set; } 
}

public class Data    
{
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; } 
}

public class Root
{
    public string id { get; set; } 
    public Data data { get; set; } 
}
```

I want `SER1` and `SER2` to map to `List<Device> Devices`, with the `Id` of `Device` getting `SER1` and `SER2` respectively.

Is this possible?

Comment: instead of a `List<Device>`, try a `Dictionary<string,Device>`

Comment: Thanks Franz, tried it but no luck

Comment: ... try a Dictionary, then look at the data you get (especially the _keys_) and think about what step you can execute _after_ deserialisation to fill the id-field ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this can be done, but you will need a custom `JsonConverter` to handle it.

First, you need to make a small adjustment to your classes, as you have an extra layer in there.  There is no `devices` member in the JSON -- there is only `data`, and that represents the list of devices.  So, change your root class to this:

```
public class Root
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("data"), JsonConverter(typeof(DeviceListConverter))]
    public List<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

You can also get rid of the `Data` class, as it is not needed.

Here is the code you will need for the custom `DeviceListConverter` class:

```
public class DeviceListConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(List<Device>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        return obj.Properties()
                  .Select(jp => new Device
                  {
                      Id = jp.Name,
                      Events = jp.Value["events"].ToObject<List<Event>>(serializer)
                  })
                  .ToList();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now you can deserialize as you normally would and it should work as you want:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```

Here is a working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qORiPG

Comment: No problem; glad I could help!